# Как отключить кеширование php-скриптов на сервере

Tags: php

Меняю файл `php` на сервере, проверяю работу в браузере. Но изменения вступают в силу не сразу, а через некоторый промежуток времени. Иногда мгновенно, иногда нужно секунд 40, бывает дольше. С чем это связано? Очень мешает при разработке. Можно ли как-то исправить?

Comment: http://ru2.php.net/manual/ru/opcache.configuration.php http://ru2.php.net/manual/ru/apc.configuration.php

Comment: Забыл сказать, что сервер виртуальный и доступа к php.ini нет

Comment: Хотя в принципе уже помогли, спасибо

Comment: Вызовите функцию opcache_reset для очистки кэша. Отключение возможно только изменяя файл php.ini и ini_set не сработает так как приложение уже будет запущено.

Answer (score 4):

В **`php.ini`** вставить вот эти две строчки:

```
opcache.enable = Off
xcache.cacher = Off
```